# Render multiple vue elements in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js, vuejs2

I had one page with 6 vue elemens in it, which one had his own separate file and i load on the same page with a render partial, then a **div** with its name, as we can see on my code. The problem is, on production, its rendering nothing, i simple get a blank HTML div with all the classes, but nothing inside, like they supose to look. I found some tips around that the production parts request another aproach from the VUE to work, using.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
```

and

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: domElement,
    render: h => h(RootComponent)
  })
```

but i cant find a way on my project to put those things to work.

Heres my **home.js** where i import the files and use then as VUE components:

```
import TurbolinksAdapter from 'vue-turbolinks';
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm';
import VCharts from 'v-charts';
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue';
import { Modal, Button } from 'bootstrap-vue/es/components';

import IndicatorsContainer from '../../admin_area/home/indicators-container';
import IndicatorsItem from '../../admin_area/home/indicators-item';
import SalesContainer from '../../admin_area/home/graphic-sales-container';
import TestsContainer from '../../admin_area/home/tests-container';
import TopCoaches from '../../admin_area/home/top-coaches';
import TopRegions from '../../admin_area/home/top-regions';

Vue.config.ignoredElements = [
  'trix-toolbar', 
  'trix-editor',
  'action-text-attachment'
]

Vue.use(TurbolinksAdapter);
Vue.use(VCharts);
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
Vue.use(Modal);
Vue.use(Button);

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
  new Vue({
    el: '#admin_area_home', 
    components: {
      'indicators-container': IndicatorsContainer,
      'indicators-item': IndicatorsItem,
      'graphic-sales-container': SalesContainer,
      'tests-container': TestsContainer,
      'top-coaches': TopCoaches,
      'top-regions': TopRegions
    }
  })
})
```

Heres my **index.html.haml** when i mount the render partials order to the page:

```
.d-block.mt-3
  = render partial: 'shared/messages'

.d-block#admin_area_home
  = render partial: 'admin_area/home/partials/indicators'
  = render partial: 'admin_area/home/partials/sales'
  = render partial: 'admin_area/home/partials/tests'
  .col-12.my-4
    .row
      .col-6.pl-0
        = render partial: 'admin_area/home/partials/top-coaches'
      .col-6.pr-0 
        = render partial: 'admin_area/home/partials/top-regions'  

= javascript_pack_tag 'admin_area/home', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
```

Each **partial** looks like this, where i pass the data through URL props:

```
%top-coaches{:title => t('.title'), :year => t('.year'), :month => t('.month'), :url_coaches_year => admin_area_home_top_coaches_year_url, :url_coaches_month => admin_area_home_top_coaches_month_url}
```

And finally each **.vue** file looks like this (i'm using the *fetch* on vue data just to check if the data is comming on .json files correctly):

```
<template>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="c-indicators__legend d-flex justify-content-between">
      <legend>{{ title }}</legend>

      <select
        id="filter"
        name="filter"
        class="form-control d-flex align-items-end col-4">
        <option value="1" selected>{{ year }}</option>
        <option value="2">{{ month }}</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="c-indicators__card">
      <div class="c-indicators__container">
        <div id="admin_area" class="container">
          <template>
              <b-table striped hover :items="items" />
          </template>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</template>

<script>
export default{
  props: [
    'title',
    'year',
    'month',
    'url_regions_year',
    'url_regions_month'
  ],
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        fetch(this.url_regions_year),
        fetch(this.url_regions_month),
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The page loads all the divs, select dropdowns and any other HTML element that i put in, but not the charts and tables that vue is supposed to render. Any advise? (warning, possible incorrect grammar arround, fell free to correct me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing `import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm';` to `import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js';` and putting

```
var homeElement = document.getElementById("admin_area_home")
  if (homeElement != null) {
```

before new Vue method, make things load now.